Could someone translate & explain the Mesorah?

I stumbled across this unusual Mesorah note and was wondering if someone could translate & explain it. I've not noticed this before in any other Tanakh and so I'm curious.

There is a practice of certain soferim (mentioned for example in Rema Yoreh Dei'ah 273:6) to write six specific words in a sefer torah at the head of a column.
The acronym for the six words is ביה שמו, but there is some debate as to the precise identity of the words (see e.g. Kol Yaakov ad loc).
This note is saying that the word שני in verse 8 is supposed to appear at the head of a column (בראש הדף), being referred to by the letter shin in the acronym ביה שמו, according to certain versions of this practice.
